# How to populate empty columns with unique values in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, unique

I have a table which have a row containing user emails and I want to add a constraint to make this row unique. The problem is that there are some (around 200) columns with empty values.

I need to generate dummy values and insert them to the empty columns.

How can I do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Description

You can use the `T-SQL` function `newid()`

> **newid()** Creates a unique value of type uniqueidentifier.

#### Sample

```
UPDATE MyTable set Column = newid() where Column is null
```

#### More Information

- [MSDN - NEWID (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190348.aspx)

Comment: @Mithrandir I think so too ;)

Answer (score 5):

If you use SQL Server 2008 - consider unique index by email which filters out null values, smth like that:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX [UX.Email, not null] on dbo.YourTable(email)
WHERE email is not null
```

**OR**

For versions of SQL Server prior to 2008 you can use the value of your primary key identity  of row, if you have one

```
update yourtable set email = id where email is null
```

If you have no such a key, at least you can use NEWID() function instead of id

Comment: @AndriyM thanks for edit - i'm writing from mobile phone - its a little bit tiresome

Comment: I've hit the reputation cap for today, so, please, revote me tomorrow 8-D